# How do I fix this Flexslider error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

When I click on the flex controls (http://aortiz.info/mirophotography/), I get 
**Not Found,** The requested URL /mirophotography/undefined was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache Server at aortiz.info Port 80)

This error seems to occur only when I use the 'scoll up' functionality.

Locally I get Not Found

The requested URL /mirophotography/undefined was not found on this server.

Comment: I don't appear to get these errors. What do you do to get the errors?

Comment: Works for me. Are you saying error occurs only locally ?

Comment: Thanks guys for responding!

@Lee: I discovered the error when I clicked the scroll up icon, Its an arrow icon on the lower right when the screen is in tablet view or smaller..

Comment: @Ani: I get it both locally and on the server I am using...